# Custom View Ignoring Delay

Tags: android

I want to change the color of a drawn rectangle every second. I have the following code to do so.

```
private Runnable mRunnable;
private int mIndex;
...

public BlinkingView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);

    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("Tag", "Millis Dif -- " + (mIndex== 0 ? "GREEN" : "RED") + " :: " + (currentMillis - lastMillis));
            lastMillis = currentMillis;

            // Set the paint color to be drawn.
            mColoredRectPaint.setColor(mIndex++ % 2 == 1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);

            // Update the view.
            invalidate();

            // Run again.
            postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };

    post(mRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Draw the colored rectangle
    canvas.drawRect(mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom, mColoredRectPaint);

    // Draw a boarder rectangle.
    canvas.drawRect(mStrokeLeft, mStrokeTop, mStrokeRight, mStrokeBottom, mOuterRectPaint);
}
```

But only every other call to `postDelayed` is delayed. I am logging out the number of milliseconds between each call to the run method of the runnable.

```
D/Tag: DURATION -- GREEN :: 1000
D/Tag: DURATION -- RED :: 1
D/Tag: DURATION -- GREEN :: 1002
D/Tag: DURATION -- RED :: 3
D/Tag: DURATION -- GREEN :: 1001
D/Tag: DURATION -- RED :: 3
D/Tag: DURATION -- GREEN :: 1001
D/Tag: DURATION -- RED :: 2
```

So every other call is being delayed. Any ideas why?

Comment: The delay will usually have a margin of error if I remember correctly

Comment: I thought it guaranteed it would be after that time but not necessarily exactly  that time. Also, a full second is a pretty big margin of error.

Comment: One thing you should clarify is your log you are referring to. And show the code exactly are you have written it.

Comment: The log is the number of milliseconds between each call to run method of the runnable.

Comment: Also do you have a reason why you have invalidate() and provide more code to outline what you are talking about, more specifically the log and where you are posting the runnable ? Also try removing the invalidate call and see if it makes a difference and dump the stacktrace as onDraw is being called so you can see where its originating from.

Comment: I invalidate to redraw the background. And even if I don't it makes no difference.

Comment: The code for posting the runnable is in there. I post it twice. Once when the view is created and in the runnable itself.

Comment: If you are calling setColor, that will automatically call invalidate usually. Calling it again may be redundant.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't. The view has no knowledge of the paint that I am using.

Comment: when i say automatically I mean when YOU call the setColor API. Also another question is how are you trigger the sequence of color calls? I see when you create the view you call it once, but after that how is it triggered again according to your 'want to change the background color of a view every second' ?

Comment: I am drawing the rectangle I want to change the color of. I am not actually changing the background property of the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156186/discussion-between-j-blaz-and-joxtraex).

Comment: I don't think its a problem with your delay, I think you should probably look at your source and confirm that you aren't creating multiple unexpected runnables. With what you posted this is the only conclusion that we can come to!

Answer (score 0):

use `Timer`

```
private Timer myTimer;

myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            // Set the paint color to be drawn.
            mColoredRectPaint.setColor(mIndex++ % 2 == 1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);

            // Update the view.
            invalidate();
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

**update:**

You can also use thread for manage your timer:

```
mThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                // Set the paint color to be drawn.
                mColoredRectPaint.setColor(mIndex++ % 2 == 1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);

                // Update the view.
                postInvalidate();

                switch (state){
                    case 1:
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mThread.start();
```

Comment: That might work for a set duration but what if I want to show 1 color for 500 millis and the other for 1000? Or provide a custom duration scheme? This isn't as flexable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the custom view. The problem is with `Handler`. I saw your post and tried to run a simple code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.println(currentTime - lastTime);
        lastTime = currentTime;
        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
handler.post(mRunnable);
```

Surprisingly, it also gave the same result.

**Conclusion: If you want the functionality to be exactly same, do not use handler. You may want to use `Thread` directly.**

Answer (score 0):

Look at below code I interpreted that would pass your test cases.

```
int tick = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tick++;
        if(tick%2==0) {
           handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
          // Set the paint color to be drawn.
           mColoredRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
           mColoredRectPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
           handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
        // Update the view.
        invalidate();
    }
}, 1000)
```